# How to get api response in option tag of select in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

My API Response :

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoSM3.png)

I need to get dropdown values from api in componentDidMount

```
axios({
          method: 'get', 
          url: url,
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTION'
          }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                //handle success
                console.log(response);                   
                if(response.data.result === true){
                    this.setState({
                      //  dropdown: response.data
                      });                   
                }               
                })
```

I need as dropdown in select in render :

```
                                   <select
                                    name="industry"
                                    className="industrydrop"
                                    >
                                <option value="">Select Industry</option>
                                      <option>
                                     {api res data array here }
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                                </select>
```

I cannot setstate and i cannot use Map,Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dropdown using data from randomUser api that renders a list of emailids in the dropdown. You can use it as a reference and add the response of your API. I have created it as a class component since I can see you are using this.setState to update your state.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropdownData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api?results=4`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ results }) => { // add your API response
        this.setState({ dropdownData: results });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { dropdownData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select key>
          {dropdownData &&
            dropdownData.map((item, index) => {
              return <option>{item.email}</option>;
            })}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think My API Response is the problem cannot set the response in the state, my response is in (res.data.data.industries) after that only i am having id and name

Comment: can you console log your response console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data)) and share it here